# Homework: error: invalid method declaration; return type required

Tags: java, oop, constructor

I am trying to create a class that will create matrices by taking an array as an input (among other things). This array will be assigned to a record (Record9). However I am getting this error when trying to compile. You can find my code below:

```
public class Matrix3x3flat {

    private class Record9 {
        public long r1c1;
        public long r1c2;
        public long r1c3;

        public long r2c1;
        public long r2c2;
        public long r2c3;

        public long r3c1;
        public long r3c2;
        public long r3c3;
    }
    private Record9 mat;

    public Record9(long[] arr) {
        Record9 this.mat = new Record9();

        this.mat.r1c1 = arr[0];
        this.mat.r1c2 = arr[1];
        this.mat.r1c3 = arr[2];
        this.mat.r2c1 = arr[3];
        this.mat.r2c2 = arr[4];
        this.mat.r2c3 = arr[5];
        this.mat.r3c1 = arr[6];
        this.mat.r3c2 = arr[7];
        this.mat.r3c3 = arr[8];

        return this.mat;
    }    
}
```

I don't understand the problem but I do suspect it has something to do with me not properly referencing this.mat in the return statement.

Answer (score 0):

Well, few things I notice. Edit: as mentioned below, constructor name needs to be the same as class name.

2) Why are you re declaring mat as a type of Record9. You already set it up top as a type of Record9, no need to define it again, you can just say this.mat = whatever it needs to be

Answer (score 0):

My idea is you want to create instance of Record9 on public Record9(long[] arr), currently you use return statement i side of constructor it is not allow. so you need to convert that to a method.

try like this :

public class Matrix3x3flat {

```
private class Record9 {
    public long r1c1;
    public long r1c2;
    public long r1c3;

    public long r2c1;
    public long r2c2;
    public long r2c3;

    public long r3c1;
    public long r3c2;
    public long r3c3;
}
private Record9 mat;

public Record9 instance(long[] arr) {
    this.mat = new Record9();

    this.mat.r1c1 = arr[0];
    this.mat.r1c2 = arr[1];
    this.mat.r1c3 = arr[2];
    this.mat.r2c1 = arr[3];
    this.mat.r2c2 = arr[4];
    this.mat.r2c3 = arr[5];
    this.mat.r3c1 = arr[6];
    this.mat.r3c2 = arr[7];
    this.mat.r3c3 = arr[8];

    return this.mat;
}
```

}